# AVR ATMega1284P USART Communication lockup

Tags: serial-port, communication, avr, usart

I am using the USART in synchronous mode to communicate from the host computer to firmware(resides in ATMega 1284P). My maximum buffer size in the firmware side is 20, If I send the data continuously from the host to the firmware and some replies from firmware to host computer, somehow the communication locks up. I doubt that the UDR register which is common for both Transmit Data Buffer(TXB) and Receive Data Buffer(RXB) to send/receive the data in/out of the firmware is locked which results in ceasing of communication. Any Suggestion for this issue?

PS:
For transmisson from firmware to host, the codition is:
UCSRA & (1 << UDRE) should be TRUE

For reception from host to firmware, the condition is:
UCSRA & (1 << RXC) should be TRUE

I am using hardware interrupt M_USARTx_RX_vect for checking the availability of the serial characters from host.

**Update:** [Firmware - Initial Source](https://github.com/ErikZalm/Marlin/tree/Marlin_v1/Marlin) : MarlinSerial.cpp : USART Definitions, Marlin_main.cpp : Program Flow

Comment: It is about embedded programming, how to use UART in atmega device. No network involved!

Comment: Do you really mean "synchronous" mode? This always uses a separate clock line. If you communicate via rs232 to the pc, you have to use asynchronous mode! maybe the problem starts here ...

Comment: No I am not using rs232, both the host(runs arch linux) and the controller are in two different boards bind together. so there is no cable involved.

Comment: uhh - wait - a UART connection without a cable? Are your Bits carried by squirrels from TX of one to RX of the other board?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch host cpu board is plugged into the mcu board.

Comment: No source, no help! Sorry! If you are not able to provide the problematic parts of your code nobody can help you here. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UDR register is physically two times present at the same address in the avr address space ( special io register mapping). There is no locking between the udr of the rx and tx of the uasrt in hardware.

The shown conditions seems ok to me, but I have not looked in the avr datasheet.

Maybe you have some problems while writing/reading to your cyclic? 20 char buffer? Please show your code ( please shrink for the minimum we need to understand ).

Comment: It is working perfectly fine, if I limit the data sent from host to firmware to be less than 20. And after that, based on the acknowledgment from firmware side to host, I send the further data. The buffers are of char type. The problem appears only if I continuously flow the data from host. Once it exceeds the limit of 20, the firmware stops responding(firmware cannot send acknowledgment and host is waiting for acknowledgment to send next data).

Comment: so please you have to show us your code and maybe we can find the problem. I am not a specialist of remote analyzing a black box :-)